# Difference between matrix rapresentation

Tags: matrix

I've noticed different behaviour in Mathematica between matrix representation:
The matrix

```
a={{1,2},{3,4}}
is different from 
b=a // MatrixForm
```

Why i obtain different results using the same matrix in command like Eigensystem?
What kind of definition should i use in my programs?

Comment: So, voting to close. But you may go on and delete your own question

Comment: Ok, i've solved the problem, but i've edited the question to understand better the difference

Comment: Perhaps #5 explains a bit: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/1517